GraalVM JDK is giving error "method 'void <init>()' not found" while instantiating bean in micronaut project
While running server, GraalVM JDK is giving error "method 'void <init>()' not found" while  instantiating bean in a Micronaut project, However, the same app is working with Java 17.

2024-12-31 16:35:41.772 [ERROR] [main] i.m.r.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [com.test.Cat] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.test.Cat]

Message: com.test.Cat: method 'void <init>()' not found
Path Taken: new Cat()

void <init>() is the no-arg constructor. Please provide a [mre].
